# How to implement this Slim 3 middleware to Slim 4 middleware

Tags: php, api, rest, slim, slim-4

I have this code from my Slim-3 middleware, how can I convert this to Slim-4 middleware. It seem in slim4, we need to return some response instead return the callable $next

```
//route middleware
$app->add(function (Request $request, Response $response, callable $next) {

   $public = array(
      "ping", 
      "guest", 
      "login",
      "api-login", 
      "logout"
   );
   
   $route = $request->getAttribute('route');

   // return NotFound for non existent route
   if (empty($route)) {
      throw new NotFoundException($request, $response);
   }

   $name = $route->getName();

   //if route is not public, then 
   // - get bearer token from authorization header / httponly cookie
   // - validate jwt token
   if (!in_array($name, $public)) {

      //get token status from cookie token
      $tokenStatus = checkTokenStatus();

      if (!$tokenStatus) {
         //redirect to guest page
         return $response->withRedirect('/login'); 
      }
   }

   return $next($request, $response);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v4/concepts/middleware.html):

You need to change the function arguments to:

```php
function(Request $request, RequestHandler $handler)
```

and then return the response by:

```php
$response = $handler->handle($request);
return $response;
```